# mySQL, setting a result value to another value within the same query

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have the following SQL statement:

```
  SELECT `entity_id`,`parent_id`,`name`
  FROM category
  WHERE is_active = 1
  ODER BY parent_id asc, position asc;
```

Which returns a result like the one below:

```
+-----------+-----------+------------+----------+
| id        | parent_id | Name       | desc     |
+-----------+-----------+------------+----------+
| 1         | NULL      | Fruit      | NULL     |
+-----------+-----------+------------+----------+
| 2         | 1         | Apple      | NULL     |
+-----------+-----------+------------+----------+
```

I'd like to update the query so it returns the corresponding Name in the parent ID field. So, my output would be like this:

```
+-----------+-----------+------------+----------+
| id        | parent_id | Name       | desc     |
+-----------+-----------+------------+----------+
| 1         | NULL      | Fruit      | NULL     |
+-----------+-----------+------------+----------+
| 2         | Fruit     | Apple      | NULL     |
+-----------+-----------+------------+----------+
```

I've been playing with this query for a while using an inner join on the same table, although I'm not sure this is the correct approach. Could anyone recommend an approach here.

Answer (score 1):

This must be this where you looking for:

```
 SELECT c.`entity_id`,c. p.`name` as parent_id, c.`name`
  FROM category c
  LEFT JOIN category p WHERE c.`parent_id = p.id
  WHERE c.is_active = 1
  ORDER BY c.parent_id ASC, c.position ASC;
```

Comment: There's a mistake in the query `ODER`

Comment: @Jonathan Parent Lévesque - Thanks

Comment: I get an error on the WHERE after the right join unfortunately.

Comment: replace `p.id` by `p.entity_id`.

Answer (score 1):

Bernd Buffen answer is right, another way to do it would be using a sub-query within the main query

```
SELECT c.`entity_id`, IFNULL((SELECT c2.`name` FROM category c2 WHERE c.`entity_id` = c2.`parent_id`), '') as parent_name, c.`name`
FROM category c
WHERE c.is_active = 1
ORDER BY c.parent_id asc, c.position asc;
```

Comment: Thanks for that, unfortunately this doesn't work across all fields. I.E. most parent.id fields are left blank, even though an ID exists with a name.

Comment: are you sure that all the parent id really exists? Are you sure that all the row have a value in the name? If the parent id is something important in your table, you should consider add a foreign key and an index. It will improve performance when reading data (reduce a little bit on writing) and ensure data integrity if the parent id is deleted.
`ALTER TABLE category
ADD KEY ak_parent_id (parent_id)
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_parent_id FOREIGN KEY (parent_id)     REFERENCES category (entity_id) ON DELETE SET NULL;`